# SonarQube background tasks failing with Multiple entries with same key

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.3

I know this is very similar problem as [SonarQube background tasks failing with IllegalArgumentException for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413589/sonarqube-background-tasks-failing-with-illegalargumentexception-for-java), but in my case I don't know where exactly the problem occurs. 
This is my log:

```
2016.02.03 13:24:22 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVKnFyTzP-Q7QH-_7ITt
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: scala=Scala and scala=Scala
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:150) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.checkNoConflictInBucket(RegularImmutableMap.java:104) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.<init>(RegularImmutableMap.java:70) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:254) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.collect.Maps.uniqueIndex(Maps.java:1166) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.collect.Maps.uniqueIndex(Maps.java:1140) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.language.LanguageRepositoryImpl.<init>(LanguageRepositoryImpl.java:46) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:262) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.AbstractComputationSteps$1.apply(AbstractComputationSteps.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.AbstractComputationSteps$1.apply(AbstractComputationSteps.java:40) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:794) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:37) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:72) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72-internal]
2016.02.03 13:24:22 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=org.codehaus.sonar:javascript-sonar-runner-lcov:iss-hipcms-269 | id=AVKnFyTzP-Q7QH-_7ITt | time=3823ms
```

The problem is that I can see only `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: scala=Scala and scala=Scala`, so I'm not sure where the problem occurs.

There was already one project before, and I used the same properties for both. Is it possible that this problem happens because I set for both of them `sonar.projectKey=org.codehaus.sonar:javascript-sonar-runner-lcov`? Or this is not that key to which error message refers? If it is, than what should I put as a `sonar.projectKey`?

Comment: Can you please list which plugins you've installed on your SonarQube instance?

Comment: I'm using Build Breaker 1.1, Git 1.1, JIRA 1.2, Java 3.9, JavaScript 2.10, SVN 1.2, Scalastyle 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, Scoverage 5.1.1
Why do you think that the problem may be caused because of the plugins?

Answer (score 3):

You are using 2 plugins (scalastyle and scoverage) which declare to SonarQube exactly the same language (scala). This is not how plugins should behave: there should be one plugin that declares the language (ideally named "sonar-scala-plugin") and other side plugins that would reference this language (but not declare it).

- [SONAR-7318](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7318) has been created on SonarQube to make sure this gets noticed earlier.
- **Edit:** [scala key duplicated #31](https://github.com/RadoBuransky/sonar-scoverage-plugin/issues/31) has been created to fix this issue on the plugin side.

Your problem should be solved once the developers of those plugins get aligned on which plugin declares the language and which other plugin references it.

Comment: so, if I delete one of these plugins, it should work? If so, then is there any other way of using both of them?

Comment: I had a similar issue with css plugin. I uninstalled one and things are back to normal now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, what i did is the following:

1. I made a sonar-scala-plugin to define the scala language and added this to my sonaqube.
2. I downloaded the sourcecode from the scalastyle plugin: https://github.com/NCR-CoDE/sonar-scalastyle and the scoverage plugin: https://github.com/RadoBuransky/sonar-scoverage-plugin
3. Then i refactored the code, in the class where the sonarplugin is extend i removed the class where the language is defined:
   My ScalastylePlugin looks as followed:

   override def getExtensions: java.util.List[Class[_ <: Extension]] = ListBuffer(
   classOf[ScalastyleRepository],
   classOf[ScalastyleQualityProfile],
   classOf[ScalastyleSensor]
   )
4. I did the same for the sonar scoverage plugin. In the class that extends the SonarPlugin i removed the classOf[Scala];
5. Then i builded all the plugins and added the plugin jar files to sonarqube.